# bibtex error: Not writing to book.blg (openout_any = p), MacTeX-2014

Tags: bibtex, moderncv, mactex, multibib

I am using a Mac, OS X 10.10.1, TeXLive, all packages up-to-date. MacTeX-2014 Distribution.

The document is based on the `moderncv` package and uses `multibib`. 
I can run LaTeX on the file, and it generates the required three `.aux` files, one for each of the bibliographies.

I then attempt to run `bibtex` against each of these `.aux` files in a terminal window using

```
bibtex /Users/mbc/Desktop/moderncv/examples/book.aux
```

`bibtex` returns the following error

```
bibtex: Not writing to /Users/mbc/Desktop/moderncv/examples/book.blg (openout_any = p).
I couldn't open file name `/Users/mbc/Desktop/moderncv/examples/book.blg'
```

I have tried to run the same command using `sudo` - same error as above.
A search for a solution suggested that the file `texmf.cnf` be edited to change `openout_any = p` to `openout_any = a` but I can not find `texmf.cnf` on my machine at all.

I suspect that configuration is handled differently in the MacTeX-2014 Distribution.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Don't use a full path. If you're using the Terminal, just do `bibtex book` after `cd`'ing to the directory `~/Desktop/moderncv/examples`

Comment: @egreg, do you know why full path is not allowed when using it from terminal?

Comment: [The error comes from TeX’s protection against writing to directories that aren’t descendents of the one where your document resides. (The restriction protects against problems arising from LaTeXing someone else’s malicious, or merely broken, document. If such a document overwrites something you wanted kept, there is obvious potential for havoc.)](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=includeother)

Comment: On a Bash shell you *could* do `openout_any=a bibtex /path/to/file.aux` Of course you should be aware of the security holes you're opening. A maliciously crafted `.bib` file could write *anything* on your file system.

Comment: Thank you - problem resolved. In the past I have dragged the file from Finder into the Terminal window - I suspect that this is common practice amongst Mac users and I wonder if it is not worthwhile decimating the shortcomings of this approach more widely?

Answer (score 4):

According to the [TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-includeother), referenced in the comments:

> ## LaTeX won't include from other directories
>
> You wanted to `\include{../bar/xyz.tex}`, but LaTeX says:
>
> ```
> latex: Not writing to ../bar/xyz.aux (openout_any = p).
> ! I can't write on file `../bar/xyz.aux'.
> ```
>
> The error comes from TeX’s protection against writing to directories
> that aren’t descendents of the one where your document resides. (The
> restriction protects against problems arising from LaTeXing someone
> else’s malicious, or merely broken, document. If such a document
> overwrites something you wanted kept, there is obvious potential for
> havoc.)
>
> Document directory structures that can lead to this problem will look
> like the fictional *mybook*:
>
> ```
> ./base/mybook.tex
> ./preface/Preface.tex
> ./preface/***
> ./chapter1/Intro.tex
> ...
> ```
>
> With such a structure, any document directory (other than the one
> where `mybook.tex` lives), seems "up" the tree from the base
> directory. (References to such files will look like
> `\include{../preface/Preface}`: the ".." is the hint.)
>
> But why did it want to write at all? — ["what's going in in my
> `\include`"](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-include)
> explains how `\include` works, among other things by writing an `.aux`
> file for every `\include`d file.
>
> Solutions to the problem tend to be drastic:
>
> Restructure the directories that hold your document so that the master
> file is at the root of the tree:
>
> ```
> ./mybook.tex
> ./mybook/preface/Preface.tex
> ./mybook/preface/***
> ./mybook/chapter1/Intro.tex
> ...
> ```
>
> and so on.
>
> Did you actually need `\include`? — if not, you can replace `\include`
> by `\input` throughout. (This only works if you don’t need
> `\includeonly`.) You could patch your system's `texmf.cnf` – if you
> know what you're doing, the error message should be enough of a hint;
> this action is definitely not recommended, and is left to those who
> can "help themselves" in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

Very often, there is not need to patch/edit texmf.cnf.
Instead create a symlink from the root of your main tex file to the directory
from which you are doing the \include or \includeonly (\input does not require the symlink).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/243140)

Comment: Many people, like myself, will land on this page as a result of a search for "openout_any = p" which is part of the question. I solved my problem with a symlink from my tex root. This may well solve other people's problem. I am often on stackexchange not to get answers but to solve problems.